# Open rtsp stream from camera using vlc

Tags: video, vlc

I have problem with recording video stream from camera using vlc.
When I run command vlc 
`rtsp://172.X.X.X/live.sdp` vlc shows video in proper way. When I run command

```
vlc rtsp://172.X.X.X/live.sdp --run-time=5 --sout=file/ps:test6.mpg vlc://quit
```

there is new created file but it weighs 0 or 4K and I can not open it. In console I got logs below. What is wrong ?

```
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[0000000000a31148] core libvlc: Uruchamianie vlc z domyślnym 
interfejsem. Użyj 'cvlc', aby używać vlc bez interfejsu.
[00007f42cc003258] mux_ps mux: Open
[00007f42cc003258] core mux error: cannot add this stream
[00007f42cc04b168] core decoder error: cannot create packetizer 
output (mlaw)
[00007f42ec002918] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007f42cc042988] core decoder error: cannot continue streaming 
due to errors
[00007f42ec002918] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007f42cc003258] mux_ps mux: Close
[00007f42cc003258] idummy demux: command `quit'
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours
the function libvlc_video_get_size returns 0 on success and -1 if it was not.
at first you should get this integer in order to see that vlc can open the url or not.
Surprisingly when I used

```
          int error = libvlc_video_get_size(vmp, 0, &video_w, &video_h);
```

the problem was fixed

Comment: Do you have any more code of your successful rtsp stream using vlc's sdk??